# Database Isolation Levels application

Tags: database, concurrency, locking, isolation-level

I understand the Database isolation levels which is very well documented in Wikipedia and Oracle documentation.

I have few questions perhaps:

1. For a particular isolation level, does database only decides the resource to lock(e.g. table, row, or data in a column) or this is configurable?
2. Other than Isolation Levels, can a user/application exclusively create lock on some resource? If not, why?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "configurable" in your first question. For the seconds, different databases have different tools, there is no general method.

Comment: Are you looking for an oracle-specific answer? (If so, it is best to add an oracle tag to the question.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oracle will automatically handle locks for all isolation levels. Oracle also lets you set locks yourself.

[How Oracle locks data](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28318/consist.htm#i5704)